# Matlab Neural Network for Confusion Matrix

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am trying to generate a confusion matrix for a linear regression model using Matlab. Here's what I have so far:

```
%read in the data: logistic.txt
table = readtable('logistic.txt');
%Assign the columns in logistic.txt to variable names in 2)
X1 = table.gre; X2 = table.gpa; X3 = table.rank; Y = table.admit;
%Fit a linear regression model and plot it:
mdl = fitlm(table, 'Responsevar','admit'); 
%plot(mdl);
%Predict the admittance of a new student input defined in assignment
sample = [780, 3.8, 2];
prediction = predict(mdl, sample)
%Generate a confusion matrix
inputvar = [X1 X2 X3];
net = patternnet(10);
net = train(net, inputvar, Y);
results = net(inputvar);
plotconfusion(Y, results)
```

logistic.txt is a four-column list of 400 rows, where "admit" is a binary response variable.
I am getting the following error:

```
Error using network/train (line 340)
Inputs and targets have different numbers of samples.

Error in hw2q2 (line 17)
net = train(net, Y, inputvar);
```

from the MathWorks examples I cannot tell exactly what I'm doing wrong.